# Turning Guessing Game into Descending Order

Tags: javascript

This script works resulting in random number. For example; when clicking on the button; you get a list that would look like this:

```
 579 too high
 520 too high
 392 too high
 273 too high
 90 too high
 58 too high
 24 too high
 6 too low
 20 too high
 19 too high
 13 too high
 9 too low
 12 Got it !!!
```

It would show random numbers both high and low mixed.
How would I make this program into a sorted list that would instead show:

```
579 too high
520 too high
392 too high
173 too high
120 too high
90 too high
87 too high
50 too high
39 too high
12 too high
9 too low
4 Got it !!!
```

How would I make this program work into Descending order?
[JsFiddle Guessing Game](https://jsfiddle.net/andrew_jsfiddle/debhxnqc/)

Code Is Here:

Guess:
    
    
 Get Number:

```
<button id="click" onclick="InsertGuess(1000,0,'',0)">Generate</button>
<div id="guess"></div>





var InsertGuess = function(max,min,finalStr,count) {
var str = 'Guessed :';
var guessnum = Math.floor(Math.random() *(max-min+1)+min);

 if(document.getElementById('index').value > guessnum){
 finalStr = finalStr.concat(guessnum , ' too low <br>');
 count=count+1;
return InsertGuess(max,guessnum,finalStr,count);
 }else if(document.getElementById('index').value < guessnum) {
 finalStr = finalStr.concat(guessnum, ' too high <br>');
 count=count+1;
 return InsertGuess(guessnum,min,finalStr,count);
 }else{
 count=count+1;
 finalStr = finalStr.concat(guessnum , ' Got it !!!<br>');
 finalStr = finalStr.concat('It took me '+ count +' tries ');
 document.getElementById('guess').innerHTML= finalStr;
 return ;
 }
 }
```

I have searched on how to descending order and ascending order; however, it won't work.

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: Your question is poorly worded, please try again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating a string, have the variable (finalStr) be an array, lets call it finalArr. Then instead of using concat, push each line as an array element;

```
 finalArr.push(guessnum , ' too low <br>');
```

Then after all pushing is done, sort the array from low to high

```
finalArr.sort();
```

You may have to look at that sort function, as it may not work well with numbers (it may treat 11 as lower than 2 for example). But I've got you started at the least.

Comment: My Question was How Would I make this program turn into descending order?

Comment: Sure. For descending order, use finalArr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});